# Syntax Error: Extra ","

Tags: formula, custom-field

It has highlighted the "," specifically before "Cold Logo" and im not sure why. this formula works in "Row level" but creating a custom object, its not. can you explain why its showing

```
If(and(LastActivityDate)<today()-30,ISBLANK(DUE_DATE),Account.Account_MRR__c<=0,Account.Number_of_Contacts__c>=1,Account.Number_of_Open_Opportunities__c=0)**,**"Cold Logo",if(AND(LastActivityDate)>=Today()-30,Account.Account_MRR__c<=0,Account.Number_of_Contacts__c>0,Account.Number_of_Open_Opportunities__c=0),"Warm Logo",if(Account.Account_MRR__c>0,"Partner Logo",IF(AND(Account.Number_of_Contacts__c=0,Account.Account_MRR__c<=0,Account.Number_of_Open_Opportunities__c=0),"No Contact Logo",IF(AND(Account.Number_of_Open_Opportunities__c>0,Account.Account_MRR__c<=0),"Pipeline Logo",if(and(Account.Account_MRR__c<=0,Account.Number_of_Contacts__c>=1,Account.Number_of_Open_Opportunities__c=0,OR(ISBLANK(LastActivityDate),ISBLANK(DUE_DATE),(LastActivityDate)<Today()-30),DUE_DATE<TODAY()-30),"Cold Logo",If(and(ISBLANK(LastActivityDate),ISBLANK(DUE_DATE),Account.Account_MRR__c<=0,Account.Number_of_Contacts__c>=1,Account.Number_of_Open_Opportunities__c=0),"Cold Logo",Null)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several extra parentheses where they don't belong. I found this by using a bracket colorizer in VS Code.

It usually helps if you indent your formula as well.

The incorrect code was:

```
LastActivityDate)<today()-30
```

Which should have been:

```
LastActivityDate<today()-30
```

This was repeated twice.

Here's the fixed version:

```
If(
    and(
        LastActivityDate<today()-30,
        ISBLANK(DUE_DATE),
        Account.Account_MRR__c<=0,
        Account.Number_of_Contacts__c>=1,
        Account.Number_of_Open_Opportunities__c=0
    ),
    "Cold Logo",
    if(
        AND(
            LastActivityDate>=Today()-30,
            Account.Account_MRR__c<=0,
            Account.Number_of_Contacts__c>0,
            Account.Number_of_Open_Opportunities__c=0
        ),
        "Warm Logo",
        if(
            Account.Account_MRR__c>0,
            "Partner Logo",
            IF(
                AND(
                    Account.Number_of_Contacts__c=0,
                    Account.Account_MRR__c<=0,
                    Account.Number_of_Open_Opportunities__c=0
                ),
                "No Contact Logo",
                IF(
                    AND(
                        Account.Number_of_Open_Opportunities__c>0,
                        Account.Account_MRR__c<=0
                    ),
                    "Pipeline Logo",
                    if(
                        and(
                            Account.Account_MRR__c<=0,
                            Account.Number_of_Contacts__c>=1,
                            Account.Number_of_Open_Opportunities__c=0,
                            OR(
                                ISBLANK(LastActivityDate),
                                ISBLANK(DUE_DATE),
                                LastActivityDate<Today()-30,
                                DUE_DATE<TODAY()-30
                            )
                        ),
                        "Cold Logo",
                        If(
                            and(
                                ISBLANK(LastActivityDate),
                                ISBLANK(DUE_DATE),
                                Account.Account_MRR__c<=0,
                                Account.Number_of_Contacts__c>=1,
                                Account.Number_of_Open_Opportunities__c=0
                            ),
                            "Cold Logo",
                            Null
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This could be heavily optimized by consolidating redundant criteria, but this should at least get you to a starting point.